# Missing body length in response to SWE request

Tags: java, web-services

I am getting this exception while invoking the webservice. Any help is appreciated.

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error Code: 10944629 Error Message: Error: Missing body length in response to SWE request!
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at com.siebel.asi.SOV_Siebel_Contact_AddressStub.queryByExample_1(SOV_Siebel_Contact_AddressStub.java:220)
    at com.siebel.xml.sovcontactaddressinfoio.TestService.checkService(TestService.java:31)
    at com.hbe.vt.action.LinkAction.executeDisplayPaymentMethods(LinkAction.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
```

Comment: [Disabling chunked streaming mode](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Foracleradio.blogspot.com.au%2F2011%2F11%2Foracle-service-bus-11g-y-web-services.html&act=url) may help, but I have no idea what the other repercussions may be.

Comment: you mean disable on the webservice server or my local client server?. ALso I already did necessary steps what the link you have provided

Comment: As I understand from the article, you should be changing this on the client side inside your `Business Service`.

Comment: so where should I change in the code. I dont see any chunk streaming mode in weblogic server.. I been looking for this solution from 2 days...

Comment: I really can't help you any further, but if you can change the HTTP headers, you should be using a "Content-Length" header instead of a "Transfer-Encoding" header. I assume you don't have access to a screen in your client system that looks like [this](http://www.xenta.nl/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/chunked-300x186.png)... More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Comment: got this fixed, like you said you need to turn off chunk mode :Runtime : User can disable the chunking using following property set in Client or Stub,
    ...
    options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, Boolean.TRUE);
    ...

Comment: Now I can see output in xml format with all the data but when it unmarshalls its giving me null object